# Angular Strap Popover $scope.$parent unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-strap

In my application I'm generating two types of popover one static and another dynamic from a given situation.

My purpose is to update a scope variable of my parent controller, I usually do this like so:

```
$scope.$parent.myVariable = 'Hello Parent';
```

Nevertheless I'm not able to access my parent from the dynamic popover.
I'm using a templated popover with [angular strap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/##popovers) and injecting it a controller.

This is my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/N27qKFcSi1DBjsvvb7tc?p=preview) example of What I want to do.

After digging a little in my popover controller $scope I discover that I'm able to get my parent (mainCtrl in the plunker example) like so:

```
 $scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.trackName ='Hello ' + $scope.name;
```

This is like a big inception but I found it :). Anyway I can't access it from the dynamic popover.

How can I get my parent from the popoverCtrl from both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one solution.

[your plunker modified](http://plnkr.co/edit/BRfCfphvH8isqatXnSX1)

1) add scope to your dynamic call to tie two scopes together.

```
scope: $scope
```

2) use object to bypass finding the correct $parent level

```
$scope.my = {};
$scope.my.name = "this is now available in all your popovers"
```

Comment: Perfect. That is an Awesome solution. :)